# How to make Log4j JDK Logging Adapter print JUL levels?

Tags: java, log4j2, java.util.logging

I'm migrating an API from JUL (Java Util Logging) to Log4j 2, so I must keep compatibility on the existing methods that expose JUL levels.

For example:

```
log(java.util.logging.Level level, String message)
```

So I decided to use the Log4j JDK Logging Adapter to keep everything working, but the default layout prints the new Log4j level.

The following code

```
Logger.getLogger("bla").severe("An issue occurred");
```

Is producing

```
ERROR: An issue occurred
```

I would like to keep the old JUL levels on the output as well, so that the migration would be transparent to user.
How can I change the layout to keep printing the old JUL levels? Like following:

```
SEVERE: An issue occurred
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

Create a [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) that directs messages of the appropriate level to an appender that can deal with them by printing the JUL level name instead of the log4j level name.

Simple Main class to test with:

```
package main.java;

import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(Main.class.getName());

        //Must set the level to FINEST in the code because the config file will not understand a custom level.
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);

        logger.info("info lvl");
        logger.finest("finest lvl");
        logger.finer("finer lvl");
        logger.fine("fine lvl");
        logger.config("config lvl");
        logger.warning("warning lvl");
        logger.severe("severe lvl");
    }

}
```

Log4j2.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%p{WARN=WARNING, DEBUG=FINE, ERROR=SEVERE, TRACE=FINER}: %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <Console name="customLevelAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%p: %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <Routing name="Routing">
            <Routes>
                <Script name="RoutingInit" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
                    logEvent.getLevel();]]>
                </Script>
                <Route ref="customLevelAppender" key="CONFIG" />
                <Route ref="customLevelAppender" key="FINEST" />
                <Route ref="consoleAppender" />
            </Routes>
        </Routing>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="main.java" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Sample output:**

```
INFO: info lvl
FINEST: finest lvl
FINER: finer lvl
FINE: fine lvl
CONFIG: config lvl
WARNING: warning lvl
SEVERE: severe lvl
```

**Note**: It seems that because FINEST and CONFIG are custom levels they can't be handled in the same way as the others. This is why there is a need for the second appender named "customLevelAppender" and why that appender does not require any special configuration.